# Cloud pages and Impressions chargin

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage, landing-page, marketingcloudapi

I was asked by one of my client if is it possible to copy an html landing page (built in Cloud Page) and paste it into one of their website page.

I think there would be no issue in that (as long as the landing page has static content), but how would it work for the impression count (and the consequent fee charge)?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi lisim. Please remember to [mark my answer as accepted](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), if it has been helpful. This will allow other users of SFSE to easily identify questions with valuable answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you by "copying a html landing page" mean, just copy pasting the HTML, then no - you will not see any charges, as this will not require the browser to perform any requests to the cloud page itself. All of the requests will go to the client's website. Only when an http requests if going to the cloud page itself, e.g. https://cloud.privatedomain.example.com/welcome your client will be charged supermessages.

You will find, that requests going to cloud page code resources, which are also able to process SSJS/Ampscript are not billable.

Comment: Thanks Lucas, very clear and useful!